DMG file disappeared after reboot
On my MacBook with MacOS Sonoma I downloaded a DMG file, moved it to Documents folder and was able to run it, but after I rebooted by MacBook it disappeared.
Does it mean that I have a corrupted file system or broken hardware?
My iCloud Settings:

DMG file is qt-creator-opensource-mac-x86_64-13.0.0.dmg. I clicked on it and then clicked on the icon:

The app (QT Creator) started, then I probably closed the app and rebooted my MacBook and qt-creator-opensource-mac-x86_64-13.0.0.dmg disappeared.
My Documents folder:


Do you have Desktop&Documents in iCloud enabled?

@nohillside No, it is disabled, see the screenshot.

You don't "run" DMG.  Do you mean that you mounted it and ran the executable inside it?  Is the DMG now gone, or is the application it contained gone?

@MarcWilson I described what I did with DMG, see updated post.

Is the file in the Trash?

@DavidAnderson no it is not

As you can see from your second screenshot, the intention of the developer is that after you double-click the .dmg file, you would then drag the application to the conveniently provided alias/soft-link to your Applications folder. This would result in the app "QT Creator" being available without needing to mount the .dmg each time.

Do you really have no other files in ~/Documents?

A .dmg file is a "disk image". It is a file that pretends to be a disk.
When you double-click on it, it gets "mounted", as if you had plugged a drive into your Mac. You'll see it listed in the sidebar, under "Locations", and you can then view the contents from there. (It's also under /Volumes in the file hierarchy.)
You can also "eject" or unmount the disk, which will remove it from the sidebar. That also happens when you shutdown your Mac.
While you can launch apps from the disk image, the intention is that you should copy them to the Applications folder on your system drive. (There's even an alias to that location, provided for you.)
Normally, you then eject the disk image, and delete the .dmg file.
Double-clicking on the .dmg file in your Documents folder should mount the disk and restore the contents that you're looking for.
